# How to get values in next row in PhpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to get values in next row?

For first for-each get the user ids. Second for-each is counts from current week to back of 3 weeks total four weeks. Search in table particular week and user id available then values was fetch and displayed but it displays in single row in Excel.

Once 4 weeks data is displayed for particular user. Next user data was printed on second row but it was not do like that? Entire data displayed in single row?

Here's my code

```
//usernames 
foreach($uname_id as $u_id)
{
  foreach($weeks as $week)
  {
    $sql="select * from attd where week_date='$week' and uname='$u_id';
    $my_sql=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($my_sql))
    {
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($bi, $bj, 
      $row['u_value']);
      $bi++;
     }
   }
}
```

[This is my wrong output sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7b1t.jpg)

[I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuwXh.jpg)

Comment: $sql="select * from attd where week_date=".$week." and uname=".$u_id;

Comment: i have fixed some errors. replace above in your code

Comment: problem not in query@bilal

Comment: Where are you incrementing `$bj` which should be your row number? Or resetting `$bi` back to the first column for each new record?

Comment: Make sure you do not have SQL injection vulnerabilities in that query, by switching to parameter binding.